# MonoCross: KeyNotFoundException in MXDialogActivityView.OnCreate() when re-starting application

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, monocross

I've been using Xamarin's Mono for Android and the MonoCross framework to develop an application, which is currently running under Android (2.3, 4.0 and others).
In my app, I have a main activity, from where the user can start new activities, which again start other activities and so on. (e.g. Main -> A -> B -> C)

From time to time, I get following problem:
When the application is paused (or stopped) for some time (i.e. not in the foreground), and/or other memory consuming apps are started, and then I return to my app, it isn't restarted correctly.
That means, I can see parts of activity C (the window title) for some seconds, then C disappears, B comes and so on with A and Main. After Main disappears, I am back on the home screen. When I again start my app, it launches with the Main activity.

In logcat, I see these entries (I hope I didn't cut too much):

```
05-15 14:36:39.732 I/ActivityManager(  598): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=de.branchare.adwais2013/branchware.adwais.droid.MainActivity u=0} from pid 1349
...
05-15 14:36:39.792 I/ActivityManager(  598): Start proc de.branchare.adwais2013 for activity de.branchare.adwais2013/branchware.adwais.droid.views.ActivityC: pid=29032 uid=10025 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
...
05-15 14:36:39.952 I/ActivityThread(29032): Pub de.branchare.adwais2013.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
...
05-15 14:36:42.966 I/MonoDroid(29032): at MonoCross.Droid.MXDialogActivityView`1<Branchware.Adwais.ModelContainer`1<Branchware.Adwais.Model.Visit>>.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x00053>
05-15 14:36:42.966 I/MonoDroid(29032): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00057>
05-15 14:36:42.966 I/MonoDroid(29032): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.15bfff07-188b-4aff-a34f-ab878a2a545f (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032):
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032): Unhandled Exception:
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032): System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Type,System.Object].get_Item (System.Type key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032):   at MonoCross.Droid.MXDialogActivityView`1[Branchware.Adwais.ModelContainer`1[Branchware.Adwais.Model.Visit]].OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
05-15 14:36:43.036 E/mono    (29032):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:15bfff07-188b-4aff-a34f-ab878a2a545f (intptr,intptr,intptr)
05-15 14:36:43.036 I/mono    (29032): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
05-15 14:36:43.036 I/mono    (29032):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Type,System.Object].get_Item (System.Type key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
05-15 14:36:43.036 I/mono    (29032):   at MonoCross.Droid.MXDialogActivityView`1[Branchware.Adwais.ModelContainer`1[Branchware.Adwais.Model.Visit]].OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
05-15 14:36:43.036 I/mono    (29032):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
05-15 14:36:43.036 I/mono    (29032):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:15bfff07-188b-4aff-a34f-ab878a2a545f (intptr,intptr,intptr)
05-15 14:36:43.136 I/ActivityManager(  598): Recipient 29032
05-15 14:36:43.136 I/ActivityManager(  598): Process de.branchare.adwais2013 (pid 29032) has died.
05-15 14:36:43.136 D/InputManager(  598): setFocusedApplication Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
05-15 14:36:43.136 W/ActivityManager(  598): Force removing ActivityRecord{41cc9df0 de.branchare.adwais2013/branchware.adwais.droid.views.ActivityC}: app died, no saved state
...
05-15 14:36:43.166 I/ActivityManager(  598): Start proc de.branchare.adwais2013 for activity de.branchare.adwais2013/branchware.adwais.droid.views.ActivityB: pid=29052 uid=10025 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
```

It seems to me as if
- Android has Destroy()ed my activities while they were paused (which I know is correct behavoir)
- Android then tries to Create() new instances of the activities when the user returns to my app (which is correct, too)
- In the framework's MXDialogActivityView.OnCreate(), MonoCross tries to fetch the model from the MXDroidContainer before calling Render():

```
// fetch the model before rendering!!!  
Model = (T)MXDroidContainer.ViewModels[typeof(T)];  
// render the model within the view  
Render();
```

- This is where the KeyNotFoundException is thrown (the method Render() is never called), because the MXDroidContainer does not contain the ViewModels any longer. (Probably this instance was also re-created in the meantime, and therefore does not contain any data.)

I know that Android can (or even must) destroy paused/stopped apps.
But it's very annoying to watch my app going back the whole activity stack and then disappearing completely, and having to re-re-start it.

What I would like to achieve is:
a) My app should restart where it stopped (in activity C).
If that's not possible, then
b) My app should restart at the MainLauncher (in activity Main), completely re-initialized.

I've already read (and played around with) a lot about activity lifecycle, launch modes, AlwaysRetainTaskState, ...
But I did not yet find a solution to my problem.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

TIA,
Manfred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your analysis of the Activity lifecycle and its interaction with the MonoCross framework is correct.

I'm not sure if MonoCross has any handling currently for this kind of 'tombstoning' - so if you want to handle this, then you'll need to do do so yourself.

To do this, you'll need to:

- use the `protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method to save/serialise any current Model data for your View into the Bundle
- override the default `MX*ActivityView.OnCreate` behaviour in order to use the `bundle` parameter which will contain the saved instance state.

I've done this same type of thing recently within MvvmCross. However, the lifecycle of models is very different in MvvmCross - I believe MonoCross always keeps exactly one instance of each model in memory, whereas MvvmCross just links each View to its ViewModel - so the ViewModel lifecyle is tied precisely to the View lifecyle. Because of this I'm afraid that Mvx code may not port easily back to MX...

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks a lot for your quick answer.  I was on holiday, so I read it just now.  I'll try the bundle-thing. I have some ListViews containing models with hundreds of entries, which does not seem to be easily (and quickly) saved in OnSaveInstanceState(). But I think I can save the parameter dictionary, and then re-navigate to the view.  Thanks again for this point.  BTW: Is there anybody out there using the MonoCross framework? I've got the impression there is not to much activity there.  Bye, Manfred.

Comment: For the BTW, I think your best bet is to ask on their Google Group. I talked to two guys from ITR at Evolve and they talking about lots of customers and users - and mentioned that their was a new release coming soon.